# After Ghostscript update 9.26 ,HP printer will not print

Tags: updates, printing, hp

After updating ghostscript to 9.26, the hp printer printed with a blue background to every print job.

Regressing to ghostscript 9.18, the printer printed fine.
Some time over the next day or three, GS had updated again to 9.26 and now did not print a blue background but would not print at all with the error message "filter failed". Regressing to 9.18 again fixed the problem.

A few days later and it has undated itself again to 9.26 and will not print, gives no error message and the print queue states that the print job is processing and proceeds no further. Regressing to 9.18 again fixes the problem.

If I update via admin -software updater (from 9.18), 9.26 is installed and will not print as described above.

Is there something wrong with GS 9.26 or with the updates that seem to happen automatically?

Is there a way of doing it manually?

Comment: More details needed: Ubuntu version. printer model and connection, hplip version.

Comment: Also please execute the command `apt list ghost* | grep installed` and append the results of that command into your question.

Comment: @NOrbert - ubuntu 16.04, hp5520, wifi connection,  don't know how to get version of hplip

Comment: @CharlesGreen - output from apt list ghost* | grep installed ->"WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts"

Comment: @NObert - hplip version - 3.16.3+repac

Comment: That's a normal error message for this command - did it list any of the ghostscript programs?

Comment: @CharlesGreen The only output from the command you suggested, was the one I posted above.

Comment: @ CharlesGreen @NOrbert, instead of updating through Software Manager, I updated using : $ sudo apt-get update, followed by : $ sudo apt-get install ghostscript. Now everything prints without problem. Thank you people for the time you have spent trying to help.

Comment: I think that this is something you should write up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: By updating (on 6/3/19) using: $ sudo apt-get update and following this with: $ sudo apt-get install ghostscript,  the printer works well.  As a check, I backdated ghostscript to 9.18 and then used the Software Updater and this time the update worked the printer well, which it didn't the previous half dozen or so times that I used it. It seems Ghostscript has finally gotten the update fixed.